# Array of structs in a struct declaration: "array type has incomplete element type"

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors, declaration

I have reduced the problem to this minimal testcase:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint64_t hash_t;
struct hash_node {
   hash_t hash;
   int offset;
   int score;
};
struct hash_leaf {
   struct hash_leaf *next;
   int entries;
   struct hash_hode node[64];
};

int main(void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

I always get the following error:

```
$ gcc foo.c
foo.c:12:18: error: array type has incomplete element type
 struct hash_hode node[64];
                  ^
```

I have used gcc 4.8.1, 4.8.3, and 4.9.0, all of which produce the same result. Is this a bug or a coding error? One comment below posted code intended for a C++ compiler, but this is being used with `gcc`, not `g++`.

Comment: What is `hash_t`, where is it defined?

Comment: What you posted compiled fine for me, as long as I've included `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/oqGZab not reproducible; it your compiler doesn't compile this exact file, it's broken; if it does, post an entire minimal file that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hash_hode is not the same has hash_node.

You have a typo...an H instead of N for NODE

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. The 'h' looks so much like the 'n' in the terminal font. Thanks!